# configuring jenkins 2.32 on centos7

Tags: centos, jenkins

i have installed jenkins 2.32 on centos7, and created two users

```
1=admin
2=sanjeev
```

problem i am facing is that when i logged in from normal user sanjeev, he can go to the configure link and is able to change the admin password, normal user should not access the admin details, please tell how to restrict normal user from accessing admin details.Check the image attached how normal user sanjeev is able to configure admin details.

[image]

Comment: Plase show how you have configured security, as I remember by default logged users can do anything

Comment: in security realm i have selected Jenkins’ own user database and in   
Authorization i have selected  Logged-in users can do anything @darvark

Comment: So you have an answer for your question. Change security settings, for example for matrix based, and setup new restrictions for users, anonymous etc. Jenkins is very very easy to configure tool

Comment: i think this is to be done using  Authentication and Authorization plugin please suggest@darvark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to grant full permissions to admin and restricted permissions to normal users under Authorization heading(in global configuration settings), below is the image

[image]